# Rails5 Bootstrap collapse not working

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

Railsnoob here. Bootstrap collapse is not properly working in my app. I tried it in a fresh created rails app but it's also not working:

My Gemfile looks like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'puma'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'coffee-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console'
  gem 'listen'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rails-controller-testing'
  gem 'minitest-reporters'
  gem 'guard'
  gem 'guard-minitest'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

app/assets/stylesheets/custom.scss:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

app/views/pages/home.html.erb
It contains the first example of the bootstrap collapse documentation:

```
<h1>Pages#home</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/pages/home.html.erb</p>

<p>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Link with href
  </a>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Button with data-target
  </button>
</p>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="card card-body">
    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
  </div>
</div>
```

I just can't figure out why it's not working. Am I missing a gem?

Edit: Found the solution, thanks to Ishwar Deoolkar :)

I added the following line in the head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

and this line at the end of the body:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Have you included bootstrap.js and jquery.js in your project folder

Bootstrap Js : https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"
Jquery Js : https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"

> Same problem was getting in my code, the accordion was not working due to bootstrap. But after including the above link in my project folder it's working for me. try this out

Comment: Thanks, this was the solution. The inclusion of bootstrap was enough ;)